# How to get a view in <router-outlet> in a main application from a children application through <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have one main Angular 8 app and three children app.

When I run any of this app everything working correctly, but any of this app sends view directly to **app.component.html** where is `<router-outlet>` not first in their **app1.component.html**, **app2.component.html** ...

I want, when I run `app1` get all view in a **app1.component.html**, where I can set different `<nav-bar>` etc, and from this get view in main **app.component.html**. I need to have different `nav`, `footer` from any of this app.

Here is **app-routing.module.ts** from my main app

```
const routes: Routes = [
     { path: "app1", loadChildren: "../../projects/mainApp/src/app/app.module#App1" },
     { path: "app2", loadChildren: "../../projects/mainApp/src/app/app.module#App2" },
     { path: "app3", loadChildren: "../../projects/mainApp/src/app/app.module#App3" },
     { path: "**", redirectTo: "/app1" }
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), 
          App1.forRoot(), 
          App2.forRoot(), 
          App3.forRoot()],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```